# Can CloudWatch import custom Elasticsearch metrics from AWS Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Amazon Elasticsearch currently sends [standard metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/es-metricscollected.html) to CloudWatch. I want to get some of the *custom* Elasticsearch metrics from my AWS Elasticsearch cluster and store them in CloudWatch. Is this possible and how can I achieve it?

Comment: Exactly.. The Cloudwatch can fetch the details of the default metrics from Elasticsearch. I want to know is it possible to write our own metrics and fetch it from AWS Elasticsearch Service. I have gone through some documents in which it is mentioned as the domain which we created on AWS Elasticsearch Service will be fully taken care by AWS only (backup, restore,etc.,). In some blogs people have posted as AWS is not allowing its users to access the APIs. 
If all the control is taken by AWS support team itself, then is it possible to access ES service and fetch our custom metrics?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clear what you are trying to do. If CloudWatch cannot retrieve your custom ES metrics, presumably you can script retrieving them and pushing them to CloudWatch.